# ARGOX printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing

I am looking for an ARGOX os-214plus PPLB driver for Ubuntu 16.04. I have been looking for a week now and I can’t find the drivers. Any ideas where I can find the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

[Their official website](http://www.argox.com/product/os-214plus/) has this to say about this printer and Linux:

> [Argox Linux Printer Driver V1.3.0(64-bit)](http://www.argox.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Argox_Linux_Printer_Driver-V1.3.064-bit.zip) (will download a zip)
>
> Ubuntu 11.10 ~ 16.04, Fedora 16 ~ 24, openSUSE 11.4 ~ 42.1, Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2, NeoKylin 6, Red Flag Linux 6, CUPS printing system for Linux (1.5 ~ 2.1.4)"

Looks like full CUPS support so this should be fairly straightforward and the printer should work perfectly after installing the zip (There is an an "install" script that needs to be executed that sets the .PPD up and restarts cups for you).

Comment: how do i install the drivers

Comment: I would assume `sudo ./install` after unzipping?